# Removing the view state of perticular repeater control

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, repeater

We have a requirement where i need to delete the view state of particular repeater from Jquery/javascript.

Example 
I have two repeater repeater 1 and repeater 2 
onclientclick of button i want remove all the data of the repeater 1 along with the particular repeater viewstate.

i am able remove the data of the repeater using

```
$(tableid).remove();
```

but view state of the repeater still exist. I can not disable the view state of the repeater otherwise few functionality will not work.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is realistically possible to do from client-side code.  You may want to look at doing some kind of asychronous postback to do it on the server side.  Even that may not work.

Comment: are you sure that you need that view state before the time you want to clean it? 
maybe you could disable it for that repeater and, if you still need to maintain some state, than store it manually in some hidden input?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that.
In this case, don't use a repeater. Create your own version of the repeater using js/jquery and html markup. You can maintain the state and load data trough callbacks using ajax.